# Removing NSButton key equivalent

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I am reusing a panel for two use cases and setting its default button accordingly. For some reason I can't remove `NSButton` key equivalent dynamically.

```
button.keyEquivalent = @"";
button.refusesFirstResponder = YES;
```

The button still retains its `\r` key equivalent, making it the default action. Is there any way to make it realize it no longer has a key shortcut?

Comment: Are you sure `button` is pointing to the correct button?

Comment: Yes. I resolved the situation (for now) by removing the button altogether and recreating them when needed. I suppose I could try subclassing `NSButton` and somehow force the key equivalent reset.

Comment: I tried your code and I don't see any issues. Post a [mre] please. Why are you setting `refusesFirstResponder` to `YES`?